# Choose segue based on condition

Tags: swift, segue

I want to choose a segue for my UITableVieController cells based on whether the data for a row matches. I have 2 segues currently (only one from the cell as that's the maximum I could do) but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    let free = allAlbums[indexPath!.row].free

    if free == "1"
    {

        if segue.destination is CaseViewController
        {
            let vc = segue.destination as? CaseViewController


            vc?.title = allAlbums[indexPath!.row].title
        }
    }
    else {
    }
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "caseDetail" {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let free = allAlbums[indexPath!.row].free
        if free == "1"
        {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "caseDetail", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "paidCase", sender: self)
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Essentially, the cell's 'free' value is 1 then it needs to go to one view controller, otherwise it will go to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `performSegue` inside `shouldPerformSegue` you need to check the value before you do the perform and act accordingly as this will cause a recursive calls as `performSegue` will call `shouldPerformSegue` again and infinitely

You need to place this inside `didSelectRowAt`

```
let free = allAlbums[indexPath.row].free
if free == "1"  {
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "caseDetail", sender: self)
}
else {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "paidCase", sender: self)
}
```

with hooking the source of the segue to the vc itself not to the cell

Comment: Perfect - sorted!